# Materialised View in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I am creating a materialised view using below command :

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW project-id.dataset_id.TESTING AS
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM project-id.dataset_id.table;
```

Below is the error:

```
Syntax error: Expected keyword AS but got "-" at [1:31]
```

I guess it's because my project id is like this : `project-id (example testing-project-dev)`.
How to resolve this ?

Comment: use back-ticks around the name \`project-id.dataset_id.TESTING\`

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant it's not working already tried that

Comment: For both reference?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant i am getting this Syntax error: Unexpected string literal `-- 'testing-project-dev.dataset_new.TESTING' at [1:26]`

Comment: As @Mikhail Berlyant said, please use grave accent mark: ``` , not quote key: ' '. Please copy following code: CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW `PROJECT-NAME.DATASET_NAME.TEST` AS
SELECT COUNT(*) name FROM `PROJECT-NAME.DATASET_NAME.BASE_TABLE`; then add `` around the name, change the table names and name of the column, which in my case is "name". Additionally, tak a look [here](https://adswerve.com/blog/quick-overview-of-materialized-views-in-bigquery/) where you will find more information regarding materialized views in bigquery

Comment: got it thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the answer from comments to an answer: Add backticks.

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW `project-id.dataset_id.TESTING` AS
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `project-id.dataset_id.table`;
```